# Spring Injection not working in different service class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

I have class

```
@Service("registrationService")
@Transactional
public class RegistrationService {

@Resource(name="registrationDAO")
 public RegistrationDAO registrationDAO;
```

In the Controller i can access registrationService and registrationDAO with no problem.

I have another class

```
@Service("securityService")
public class SecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

 protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("service");

 @Resource(name="registrationDAO")
 public RegistrationDAO registrationDAO;


  public String test(){
        logger.debug(registrationDAO.findUserByID(1) );
    return "Testing";
  }
```

Now if i call test function in controller then it gives null pointer exception on registrationDAO

Answer (score 3):

All your `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Controller`, `@Component` (etc.) annotated class must be spring-managed for autowiring to work. Make sure they are picked up by spring classpath scanning:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company" />
```

In some cases `@Autowire`, which does autowiring by type, can be useful to avoid the `name` argument you're supplying with the `@Resource`.

Comment: both service classes are in same directory then why injection works with one class and not with other

Comment: @Pasha, And when you instantiate `SecurityService` you're not using the `new` keyword anywhere?

Comment: no , i only use @Resource. all the auto injection dependencies like sessionFactory inside registrationDao are not loaded if i use from SecurityService but work from regisTration service

Comment: @Pasha, assuming they are in the same package and injected similarly both should work. I would probably examine spring behaviour using `debug` logging. Also, you are using [`...stereoptype.Service`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) right?

Comment: how can i do that , u mean logging messages in console

Comment: Use e.g., `log4j` and configure `org.springframework` to [`debug`](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat)