# Spring Injection not working if i use "implements" in class

Tags: java, dependency-injection, spring-security

This was my previous SO question 
[Spring Injection not working in different service class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437331/spring-injection-not-working-in-different-service-class)

```
@Service("securityService")
@Transactional

    public class SecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

     protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("service");

     @Autowired
     public RegistrationDAO registrationDAO;


      public String test(){
         logger.debug(registrationDAO.findUserByID(1) );
        return "test";
      }
```

In above code registrationDAO is not properly injected and give null pointer exception but Now i have found that if i remove implements from class then it works like below

```
@Service("securityService")
@Transactional

    public class SecurityService {

     protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("service");

     @Autowired
     public RegistrationDAO registrationDAO;


      public String test(){
         logger.debug(registrationDAO.findUserByID(1) );
        return "manta";
      }
```

I need to use that interface to use spring security authentication , so what should i do

Stack trace

```
enter code here
  java.lang.NullPointerException
com.vaannila.dao.RegistrationDAOimpl.findUserByID(RegistrationDAOimpl.java:63)
com.vaannila.service.SecurityService.loadUserByUsername(SecurityService.java:68)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->


    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
     For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
     <bean id="userService" class="com.vaannila.service.UserServiceImpl" />

    <bean id="userValidator" class="com.vaannila.validator.UserValidator" />

     <bean id="userDAO" class="com.vaannila.dao.UserDAO" />
     <bean id="registrationDAO" class="com.vaannila.dao.RegistrationDAO" />

    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
    Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->


</beans>
```

Comment: Please give the stack trace of the NullPointerException, we can't guess for you :)

Comment: We need to see your spring config XML.

Comment: I'm a little confused - your text says you get a `NullPointerException`, but you've posted a stack trace from a `HibernateException`. There's nothing in your spring config that would initialise Hibernate, so I think we're still missing some information.

Comment: I chnaged the stack , actually i rmeoved the @Transactional , so i get that error , now i have put back mon security service and got null pointer error again

Comment: It looks like the autowiring is working correctly, as registrationDAOImpl is getting wired, but the NPE is happening inside registrationDAOImpl.findByUserId() on line 63.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to Spring as well, but when I had this problem and it didn't work, I added a set method after the autowired, like this:

```
@Autowired
public RegistrationDAO registrationDAO;
public void setRegistrationDAO(RegistrationDAO registrationDAO) {
    this.registrationDAO = registrationDAO;
}
```

That's what worked for me, and I use it for the same thing, the DAOs that are declared in your servlet container xml file.  In some cases I tried it without the setter and it did not work.

Good luck!