# Instantiate a library class using Spring autowire constructor injection

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Given I need an instance of `LibBean` interface from an library I do not control in my Spring(-Boot)'s context and the library provides `DefaultLibBean` classes with an parameterized constructor.

is it possible to emulate @Component behaviour (constructor injection) instead of specifying the parameters manually?

```java
@Bean
LibBean libBean(AnotherBean anotherBean){
    return new DefaultLibBean(anotherBean);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [How to inject spring injection manually if not done automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450073/how-to-inject-spring-injection-manually-if-not-done-automatically) you can use the `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` for that:

```java
@Bean
LibBean libBean(AutowireCapableBeanFactory awbf){
    return awbf.createBean(DefaultLibBean.class);
}
```